# How to set current date and time in a textview inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

There's a duplicate question but we have different perspective of how were going to implement it. Mine will be displayed automatically once the app runs, and aside form that, above the textview for date is a Material Calendar Design which I've implemented in a fragment. So my question is the title it self.

Heres my code in **ScheduleFragment.java**:

```
package com.example.guitarista.citem;


import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.icu.util.TimeZone;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.CalendarDay;
import com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.CalendarMode;
import com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView;
import com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.OnDateSelectedListener;

import java.util.Date;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {


    public ScheduleFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        getActivity().setTitle("My Schedule");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textDate2);
        tv.setText(currentDateandTime);

        final MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        materialCalendarView.state().edit()
                .setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)
                .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(1900, 1, 1))
                .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2100, 12, 31))
                .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.MONTHS)
                .commit();

        materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (materialCalendarView.getSelectedDate().equals(CalendarDay.from(2017, 0, 1))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NEW YEAR!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (materialCalendarView.getSelectedDate().equals(CalendarDay.from(2017, 1, 14))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Happy Valentines Day!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

I know there's a code already for setting the current date and time, but the app will not function properly (e.g. "App stopped working"), so do you guys have another solution?

here is the **logcat**

```
01-18 10:39:05.061 26486-26486/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-18 10:39:05.071 26486-26486/? V/appproc: App process: starting thread pool.
01-18 10:39:05.089 26486-26500/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
01-18 10:39:05.090 26486-26500/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-18 10:39:05.094 26486-26486/? D/Proxy: setHttpRequestCheckHandler
01-18 10:39:05.109 26486-26486/? D/wangcy9: setStatusIcon occur wrong theme!
01-18 10:39:05.184 26486-26509/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-18 10:39:05.188 26486-26486/? D/ViewRootImpl: loadSystemProperties PersistDebugEvent: false RoDebugEvent: false
01-18 10:39:05.218 26486-26509/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017_msm8916_64_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU ()
                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
                                               Build Date: 04/29/15 Wed
                                               Local Branch: mybranch9502464
                                               Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.1.3_rb1.12
                                               Local Patches: NONE
                                               Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017 + 26a3cba + 6f69ea6 + 8bc2bc8 + 649fcde + a52cccf + dbf281f + 15f0bf8 +  NOTHING
01-18 10:39:05.219 26486-26509/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-18 10:39:05.229 26486-26509/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: PartialUpdate status: Disabled
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Left Align: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Width Align: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Top Align: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Height Align: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Min ROI Width: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Min ROI Height: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Needs ROI Merge: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Dynamic Fps: Disabled
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Min Panel fps: 0
01-18 10:39:05.234 26486-26509/? I/qdutils: Max Panel fps: 0
01-18 10:39:05.321 26486-26486/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@12412c01 time:193527594
01-18 10:39:09.889 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.guitarista.citem time:193532162
01-18 10:39:09.896 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-18 10:39:09.926 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-18 10:39:09.940 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem D/wangcy9: setStatusIcon occur wrong theme!
01-18 10:39:10.228 26486-26505/com.example.guitarista.citem I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1161(54KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 48MB/81MB, paused 5.124ms total 22.066ms
01-18 10:39:10.309 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem D/ViewRootImpl: loadSystemProperties PersistDebugEvent: false RoDebugEvent: false
01-18 10:39:10.457 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@202b8645 time:193532731
01-18 10:39:14.121 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-18 10:39:14.122 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.guitarista.citem, PID: 26486
                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat;
                                                                                  at com.example.guitarista.citem.ScheduleFragment.onCreateView(ScheduleFragment.java:46)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.guitarista.citem-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                  at com.example.guitarista.citem.ScheduleFragment.onCreateView(ScheduleFragment.java:46) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat
                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                        ... 16 more
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
01-18 10:39:17.882 26486-26486/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26486 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Show crash logs

Comment: Show logcat so we can check that

Comment: Post the logcat please

Comment: Ill update the description.

Comment: description updateed with logcat

Comment: You've got the wrong `SimpleDateFormat` class imported. It should be `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thank you bro! Already working now :) @MikeM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were import wrong library.
Go top of your Fragment, change

```
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

to

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't produce any crashes and runs perfectly for me.

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis(); SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM MM dd, yyyy h:mm a"); String dateString = sdf.format(date); textView.setText(dateString);
```

Comment: tried this code before, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. have you tried it in a fragment?

Comment: Yes. I used it in a fragment itself. :(

Comment: I think my materialcalendarview is conflicting with the setcurrentdate it self.